# Poisson random variable with parameter lambda~uniform(0, 10)

Tags: statistics

Suppose $N\sim Poisson(\lambda)$ and $\lambda\sim Unif(0, 10)$ what is the expected value $E(N)$?

I feel like I should just plug in the expected value of Unif(0, 10) but that seems too easy.  Anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

${\rm E}(N) = {\rm E}{\rm E}(N|\lambda ) = {\rm E}(\lambda ) = 5$.

Elaborating. By the law of total expectation,
$$
{\rm E}(N) = {\rm E}{\rm E}(N|\lambda ).
$$
To show that ${\rm E}(N|\lambda ) = \lambda$, note that,
given $\lambda = s$, $N$ has mean $s$. Hence, ${\rm E}(N|\lambda =s) = s$,  and in turn  ${\rm E}(N|\lambda ) = \lambda$. Thus ${\rm E}(N) = {\rm E}(\lambda) = 5$.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot.